# Is there a module for creating images and labelling and placing them in a document?

Tags: media, input-formats

I am looking for a module which allows me to place images with additional information to the text of a page using a filter connected to the image's node id.

I need a content type with something with fields like this:

1. The image itself
2. A description
3. Additional fields with some information about the image, like source, size, attribution, date, license, etc

What I need is something like a filter that allows me to embed the image in a document displayed with some of the additional fields in a properly formatted manner.

Is there a module for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

No such module exists.  The default *Article* content type in Drupal 7 already has an image field, but not  the fields you request for holding metadata.

However, with **Fields** in core in Drupal 7, it is trivial to add the required fields to any content type.  If you're not familiar with **Fields**, you may want to look at [this tutorial](http://heim.ifi.uio.no/gisle/staging2/drupalprimer/drupal/cf_field.html).

After adding the field for the image itself, and the metadata you want, you may want edit the template for the content type to make sure all the fields are rendered nicely.